# How is this matrix transformation right? (Beginner)

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

I am stuck on a question because I am not fully sure how the matrix stack works in this case.
If someone can give me step by step process that indicates what happens in this example here:
The answer is given with the question.[image]

Comment: Can you narrow down your problem description? It is okay that there is something you don't understand, but what *do* you understand? What common knowledge do we have that we can use to explain this? What specifically, is your problem? The question as stated is unfortunately too broad.

Comment: I know the Translation part which is simple. The only thing I struggle to understand is the ORDER OF EXECUTION FOR EACH STATEMENT THERE.

Comment: Let C be the current coordinate (as opposed to perspective) transformation matrix, then a transformation T will modify the current coordinate transformation matrix by C = TC. So when you draw something after a coordinate transformation, the coordinates (let it be v) will be multiply by current coordinate transformation matrix (Cv) to get the coordinate in the original coordinate to render the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us refer to the balls in the correct answer as such (the number is also the drawing order):

```
4 - 2
3 1 -
```

We starts from (0, 0) and translate to (2, 0). And we draw the ball 1. Nothing fancy here.

We save the current transformation matrix.

Then we translate by vector (2, 2) from (2, 0), so we end up at (4, 2). And we draw the ball 2. Also not tricky.

The we pop the matrix. It means that it discards all transformation up until the last push. So we end up back to (2, 0), which is where we push the transformation matrix earlier.

We translate by vector (-2, 0) from (2, 0), so we end up at (0, 0), and we draw ball 3.

Then we translate by vector (0, 2) from (0, 0), so we end up at (0, 2), and we draw ball 4.

Comment: Hi, I understood that perfectly but the part that confuses me is that dont the matrix transformation start from the right most matrix.

Comment: For example PQRS = P(Q(R(Sv))) ?? So the right most matrix is multiplied first

Comment: So would it not be fair to say that the bottom statement would get executed first?

Comment: @Jay: No, the tompost statement gets executed first. Also, since the matrix is multiplied as you wrote, the first matrix in the code would be S, the second R etc. The stack only saves and restores state, it doesn't change it in any way.

Comment: Do the topmost statement always get executed first? I am confused